# Can a Sorcerer/Paladin use Twinned Spell with Find Steed to affect more than two targets?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, metamagic, mount

I have a Sorcerer/Paladin multiclass, and I've picked up the *Magic Initiate* feat to gain *Find Familiar*. When riding into battle, I have my mount from my *Find Steed* spell and my familiar with me. If I cast something like *Haste* or *Dragon's Breath* on myself, it would also affect my mount.

But, if I use *Twinned Spell* on it to also give the buff to my familiar, **does that mean that the spell is no longer targeting only me, and therefore cannot affect my mount**?

Or does the nature of Twinned Spell bypass this somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, this will not work

Twinned Spell

> When you cast a spell that **targets only one creature** and doesn’t have
> a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the
> spell’s level **to target a second creature** in range with the same spell
> (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip). ([PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/classes#Metamagic))

(emphasis mine)

So, when you use *Twinned Spell* you are targeting an additional creature thus conflicting with the one target restriction for that effect in *Find Steed*:

> ...you can make any spell you cast that **targets only you** also
> **target your steed** ([PHB](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed))

(emphasis mine)

The same is true in the reverse case as well; using the spell sharing feature of *Find Steed* also results in multiple targets thus making it invalid for use with *Twinned Spell*.

Jeremy Crawford seems to support this as well in his description of Twinned Spell:

> [Twinned Spell] lets you **add another target to a spell** but only if that spell on its own can target only one creature and it's also not a spell that has a range of self. ([Dragon Talk 1/19/17 20:40](http://podbay.fm/show/189053885/e/1484843400?autostart=1))
> (emphasis mine)

## Official Ruling

Jeremy Crawford [made](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/801602481906012160) an almost identical ruling for the case of *split enchantment* (a wizard enchantment ability)

> Split Enchantment and Twinned Spell are mutually exclusive. **When you use one of them, the spell no longer targets only one creature.**

Split enchantment says:

> ...when you cast an enchantment spell of 1st level or higher that targets only one creature, **you can have it target a second creature**.

This is an almost identical case to the case of Find Steed and Twinned spell. Thus the ruling absolutely applies here as well.

Both of these Spells *change* a one target spell into a spell that targets two creatures. No matter how you cut it, after using either of these abilities, you now have a spell that is targeting more than one creature. Thus is ineligible. It very clearly no longer "targets only you" or "targets only one creature".

Comment: See that quote says "on its own" which seems to me would support that you could twin it because something like Cure Wounds can, on its own, only target one thing, the Find Steed extends it after the fact. I suppose I should remove my answer except I interpret that differently but Crawford also says that it was intentionally written with that ambiguity.

Comment: That is a fair point though, but I think that  the reason he said that (and this is not official game text) was to differentiate it from the extra slot he is talking about getting from Twinning and not meaning anything further. But as you said, this is my interpretation.

Comment: Just going to remove my answer (been oncall and just too tired)... I can see an argument for the extreme edge case and probably would allow it (if I allowed multi-classing for those classes). Crawford's word clarify a great deal but his choice of words at certain points are unclear on intent. Targeting is explicitly left to the DM to a certain extent until revisions and other publications come out to clear up the ambiguity. "On its own" to me would be the way I would sell this to your DM if you wanted to argue the point. Thanks @Rubiksmoose.